# Add to SharePoint's dictionary

Tags: spellchecker

Is it possible to add entries to the SharePoint 2010 spellchecker's dictionary? Also, does SharePoint's editor have any auto-complete functionality like in Word 2010?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Spell Check dictionary** for SharePoint 2010

1. Create a text file on your local machine and add each custom term on a seperate line, save the file as "Custom Dictionary.txt"
2. Create a library within the root of the site collection, call it "Spelling"; upload your "Custom Dictionary.txt" file to the library

Answer referred from [this post](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/How-to-Add-words-to-the-spell-check-dictionary-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, Deepu. Any solution for "auto-correct" of words? Or is that something we'd use the reusable content library for?

Comment: I followed the steps but can't get it working. It's in the root of the site collection. Does each web site need to have this added manually?

Comment: Its working perfectly for me even in a subsite. You need to upload the file just one time into the root site of the site collection. You will have to upload this multiple times if you have to access this under different site collections. Also, make sure your library name is "Spelling".